# Spark Dataset -Aggregate query to sum of BigInt sums as zero

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset of type ExpenseEntry. ExpenseEntry is a basic dat structure to keep track of `amount` spent on each `category`

```
case class ExpenseEntry(
    name: String,
    category: String,
    amount: BigDecimal
)
```

Example values -

```
ExpenseEntry("John", "candy", 0.5)
ExpenseEntry("Tia", "game", 0.25)
ExpenseEntry("John", "candy", 0.15)
ExpenseEntry("Tia", "candy", 0.55)
```

Expected answer is,

```
category - name - amount
candy - John - 0.65
candy - Tia - 0.55
game - Tia - 0.25
```

What I want to do is, get the total amount spent per cause per name. So, I have the below dataset query

```
dataset.groupBy("category", "name").agg(sum("amount"))
```

The query seems right to me theoretically. However, the sum is showing as `0E-18` which as 0. I am guessing the amount is getting typecast to `int` inside the `sum` function. How do I cast it to BigInt? Is my understanding of the issue right?

Comment: I figured there was an issue with my dataset itself. The code I had worked as expected. Both answers below are good alternative ways for the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object SumBig extends App{

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class ExpenseEntry(
                           name: String,
                           category: String,
                           amount: BigDecimal
                         )
  val df = Seq(
  ExpenseEntry("John", "candy", 0.5),
  ExpenseEntry("Tia", "game", 0.25),
  ExpenseEntry("John", "candy", 0.15),
  ExpenseEntry("Tia", "candy", 0.55)
  ).toDF()

  df.show(false)

  val r = df.groupBy("category", "name").sum("amount")
  r.show(false)

//      +--------+----+--------------------+
//      |category|name|sum(amount)         |
//      +--------+----+--------------------+
//      |game    |Tia |0.250000000000000000|
//      |candy   |John|0.650000000000000000|
//      |candy   |Tia |0.550000000000000000|
//      +--------+----+--------------------+

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use bound() to limit the decimals
2. Sum wont change the data type of the column from decimal to int.

```
df.groupBy("category", "name").agg(  sum(bround( col("amount"),2) ).as("sum_amount")).show()
```